# Heading Tag with flexbox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I want that the content of the span tag is right aligned and the header tag left aligned in the same row. But it seems not working.

```
<div class="ibox-body mb-5">
      <h6 class="mt-5 mb-2 d-flex align-items-start">Users</h6>
      <span class="d-flex align-items-end">10</span>
 </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems you using Bootstrap 4, if yes then just add class `d-flex justify-content-between` in container element:

```
<div class="ibox-body d-flex justify-content-between mb-5">
  <h6 class="mt-5 mb-2 d-flex align-items-start">Users</h6>
  <span class="d-flex align-items-end">10</span>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="ibox-body d-flex justify-content-between mb-5">
      <h6 class="mt-5 mb-2 d-flex align-items-start">Users</h6>
      <span class="d-flex align-items-end">10</span>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using [`flex`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/) classes

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between bd-highlight mb-3 pr-2 align-items-center">
        <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Users</div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle">4</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

For rounded background I have used custom CSS you can use default bootstrap classes

**CSS**

```
.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

**Output**

[image]